# Copy float data to varchar from table to another after excel import

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hello I have imported data from Excel via `Import and Export wizard` to my SQL Database 2008. When importing some of the columns were detected as `nvarchar` and some of them as `float`. I imported all data successfully.

Now I want to copy those data to another table thourgh this query:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.klient
  (name, surname,rodcis,nopass,street,zip,city,appendix,tel,fax,titul,akce,rocnik)
SELECT [nameorig], [surnameorig],[rodcisorig],[nopassorig],[adresa],[zip],[city],[apporig],[telhomeorig],[telworkorig],titul,'000000-00',2014
  FROM dbo.UCAST3$
```

E.g. column `rodcisorig` contain values like:

```
7102112688

500722142

515524172
```

Those columns, that were detected as `float` when I try to copy them to `varchar` column I get from mentioned cells values like this:

```
5.25317e+009

6.15131e+009
```

Would somebody help me solve this out please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change those column types from float to decimal. Then you won't have the scientific notation issue. Decimal converts to varchar the way you want it to.

If you can't change your column from float to decimal, do some workaround like this:

```
select cast(cast(YourValue as decimal) as varchar)
```

This temporarily converts your float to decimal before turning it into a varchar, dodging the issue.

Answer (score 1):

**Test Data**

```
DECLARE @t TABLE (VALUE FLOAT)
INSERT INTO @t VALUES (7102112688468486),(58468484600722142),(5684684615524172)

SELECT * FROM @t

╔══════════════════════╗
║        VALUE         ║
╠══════════════════════╣
║ 7.10211268846849E+15 ║
║ 5.84684846007221E+16 ║
║ 5.68468461552417E+15 ║
╚══════════════════════╝
```

**Query**

```
SELECT CAST(VALUE AS NUMERIC(38,2)) Vals
FROM @t
```

**Final Result**

```
╔══════════════════════╗
║         Vals         ║
╠══════════════════════╣
║ 7102112688468486.00  ║
║ 58468484600722144.00 ║
║ 5684684615524172.00  ║
╚══════════════════════╝
```

**Convert to Varhcar**

```
SELECT CAST(CAST(VALUE AS NUMERIC(38,0)) AS VARCHAR(1000)) Vals
FROM @t

╔═══════════════════╗
║       Vals        ║
╠═══════════════════╣
║  7102112688468486 ║
║ 58468484600722144 ║
║  5684684615524172 ║
╚═══════════════════╝
```